# Wrap text inside a div instead of expanding it

Tags: css

Note: My div has an auto width, and I would like to keep it that way. I think my problem would be solved if I somehow figured out how to give it a max-width equal to its current (auto) width, using CSS, but I haven't found anything.

Problem:
[image: Problem, (ignore the background text, the div on which the messages show is transparent.)]
(ignore the background text, the div on which the messages show is transparent.)

Desired width at which line should break:
[image: Desired width at which like should break]

Here's my CSS:

```
div.chat div#chatOutput {
   height: 370px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   max-height: 450px;
   min-height: 130px;
   border: 1px solid;
   overflow-y: scroll;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div class="chat">
            <h4><a title="Click to copy channel link" href="#">#</a> <span id="chatChannelName">General</span></h4>
            <div id="chatOutput"></div>
            <br />
            <div class="chat-group">
                <input type="text" maxlength="80" class="form-control" id="chatInput" placeholder="Type your message.." />
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="chatSend"><i style="float: none;" class="fa fa-send"></i> Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add your code snippet here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `overflow:`

some attributes:
`visible | hidden | scroll | auto | inherit`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add another `div` around your current `div` and give it a fixed width. This should prevent the inner div from getting bigger than the outer `div`.
Here is an example:

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed">
    <div class="autosize">
        <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    width: 400px;
}

.autosize {
    /* Your own autosize-code */
}
```

Comment: I already have, but I would like to keep the parent `div` without any specific width so it expands to match the width of it's content.